# Qt OpenGL OSX rendering slow, Windows fast on same machine

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl

I am rendering a mesh using OpenGl through Qt. (Qt 5.4).

On my OSX computer the rendering is relatively slow.  When I rotate the mesh I can see that the rendering can't keep up with my mouse input.

On the same OSX computer when running a Windows 7 virtual machine and my application the rendering is silky smooth.  It almost looks like the Mac version is rendering in software mode, instead of using acceleration.

I used glGetString to check the vender and renderer being used and this looks ok:

```
"NVIDIA Corporation"
"NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M OpenGL Engine"
```

Any ideas why the native OSX generated code would run so much slower.

BTW: I am rendering a mesh composed of about 150,000 vertices using a `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

I am quite new to OpenGL, any ideas?

Comment: You need to show a minimal case that reproduces this issue. Without it, the question is useless. We can't possibly imagine all the ways your code could be broken. Do remember that quite a bit of Windows code and drivers has workarounds for broken applications. You might be triggering such workaround, unknowingly.

Comment: Fair enough, I left the question open to see if anyone had encountered a problem like this.  My gut feeling was that it has something to do with Qt and not the openGL code.  I will post a minimal case in another question.

Comment: The minimal case belongs in **this question**! The question will be closed otherwise, and you might face a suspension for posting useless questions - they waste everyone's time. Qt does nothing much to OpenGL. About the only possible issue is the default use of indirect rendering in `QOpenGLWidget`. Try it with `QGLWidget` first, if it's still slow there, then the problem has zero to do with Qt - a `QGLWidget` is a very thin shim above the platform GL window. It won't slow you down. And really the only impact of `QOpenGLWidget` is indirect rendering - this matters not on PCs usually.

Comment: Yes - please close this question then.

Comment: You are right, it is one of the opengl calls that is causing the slowdown.  It has something to do with a texture that I am passing to a shader.  I will need to investigate why this is causing a problem on OSX.  Anyways I don't believe that problem will apply to this topic anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question so that it can be closed.

As [Kuba Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329652/kuba-ober) indicated in the comments above the problem was caused by an opengl mistake that Windows appeared to be hiding.  In my case I forgot to call the `QOpenGLShaderProgram::disableAttributeArray()` function, ex:

```
program->enableAttributeArray(texcoorLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(texcoorLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, uv);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, elementCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
program->disableAttributeArray(texcoorLocation);  //<-- this line was missing
```

It seems Windows forgave this problem, while OSX did not.